# fetch не отправляет переменные из formData

Tags: javascript, websocket, fetch, create-react-app

Вот три моих fetch кода, они выполняются в сервере после запроса с клиента. Первые два fetch кода выполняются правильно, все отправляется, а последний прилетает ответ о неизвестной переменной, хотя все одно и тоже, никак не могу выяснить в чем проблема, это же бред какой-то.

```
    io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
    socket.on('connection', (data)=>{
        var cookie = data;
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('cookie', cookie);
        fetch(
            'http://localhost/test/vivodstatusconnect.php',
            {
                method:'POST',
                header:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',},
                body: formData,
            })
            .then (response => response.text())
            .then(response => {
                io.emit('connectusercheck', cookie);
            })

        socket.on('disconnect', (socket) =>{
            var cookie = data;
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('cookie', cookie);
            fetch(
                'http://localhost/test/vivodstatusdisconnect.php',
                {
                    method:'POST',
                    header:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',},
                    body: formData,
                })
                .then (response => response.text())
                .then(response => {
                    io.emit('disconnectusercheck', cookie);
                })
        })
    })
})

io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
    socket.on('messagesend', (data) =>{
        var senders = data.sender;
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('sender', senders);
        fetch(
            'http://localhost/test/sendmessageusers.php',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',},
                body: formData,
            })
            .then (response => response.text())
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                io.emit('globalmessage', (data));
            })
    })
})
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ошибку, которую получаете. У меня угадать не получилось

Comment: Немного покопавшись заметил, что у меня та же проблема, когда я пытаюсь с клиента напрямую отправить ajax запрос, при помощи библиотеки jQuery, в первый раз у меня вылетела ошибка "Illegal invocation", решил ее добавив строку "processData: false", результатом стало, что ошибка ушла, а проблема с нечитаемыми переданными переменными осталась, очень странная фигня, в то время как другие в этом же документе ajax запросы работают исправно и без processData: false

Comment: К сожалению, понятнее не стало. Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте необходимую фактуру с ошибками, скринами(при необходимости)

Comment: Вот ошибка с Apache сервера на который отправляю:
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "message" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\sendmessagedual.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />

Comment: С клиента:
Illegal invocation
TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at add (http://10.10.10.10:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19916:51)
    at buildParams (http://10.10.10.10:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19905:7)
    at buildParams (http://10.10.10.10:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19901:9)
    at jQuery.param (http://10.10.10.10:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19933:9)
    at Function.ajax (http://10.10.10.10:3000/static/js/bundle.js:20443:25)
    at sendmessagesdual (http://10.10.10.10:3000/static/js/bundle.js:373:51)
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.<anonymous> (http://10.10.10.10:3000/static/js/bundle.js:352:9)

Comment: `C:\xampp\htdocs\test\sendmessagedual.php</b> on line <b>4</b>` - это к вопросу вообще не имеет отношения и что там никому(крове вас) не известно. [Illegal invocation TypeError: Illegal invocation at add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324594/jquery-illegal-invocation)